# LINQ read XML to List gives Object Reference for unknown node?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have a queue of XML's which are reading via linq as follows:
Sample XML

```
[XML Link](http://www.hattem.nl/roonline/0269/plannen/NL.IMRO.0269.OV165-/NL.IMRO.0269.OV165-VG01/g_NL.IMRO.0269.OV165-VG01.xml)
```

C# Code

```
    List<String> PlanInfo = new List<string>();
    XDocument xdoc = null;
    XNamespace ns = null;
    try
    {
        //List<String> PlanValuesList = new List<string>();
        xdoc = XDocument.Load(gLink);
        ns = xdoc.Root.Name.Namespace;

        var test = (
            from planInfo in xdoc.Descendants(ns + "Plan").Descendants(ns + "Eigenschappen")
            from Onderdelen in xdoc.Descendants(ns + "Onderdelen")
            select new
            {
                Naam = (string)planInfo.Element(ns + "Naam").Value ?? string.Empty,
                Type = (string)planInfo.Element(ns + "Type").Value ?? string.Empty,
                Status = (string)planInfo.Element(ns + "Status").Value ?? string.Empty,
                Datum = (Convert.ToString(planInfo.Element(ns + "Datum").Value).IndexOf("T") > 0) ? (string)planInfo.Element(ns + "Datum").Value.Substring(0, Convert.ToString(planInfo.Element(ns + "Datum").Value).IndexOf("T")) : (string)planInfo.Element(ns + "Datum").Value ?? string.Empty,
                Versie = (string)(planInfo.Element("VersieIMRO") ?? planInfo.Element("VersieGML")) ?? string.Empty,//Convert.ToString(planInfo.Element(ns + "VersieIMRO").Value) ?? String.Empty,
                VersiePraktijkRichtlijn = (string)planInfo.Element(ns + "VersiePraktijkRichtlijn").Value ?? string.Empty,
                BasisURL = (string)Onderdelen.Attribute("BasisURL")
            }).ToList();

        foreach (var item in test)
        {
            PlanInfo.Add(item.Naam);
            PlanInfo.Add(item.Type);
            PlanInfo.Add(item.Status);
            PlanInfo.Add(item.Datum);
            PlanInfo.Add(item.Versie);
            PlanInfo.Add(item.VersiePraktijkRichtlijn);
            PlanInfo.Add(item.BasisURL);
        }
 }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Error reading GeleideFormulier link for the plan and manifest
        throw;//Just throwing error here, as it is catched in the called method.
    }

    return PlanInfo;
```

In some XML files "versieIMRO" tag becomes "versieGML", which gives me error as Object Reference Not set to an instance of an object.

Please let me know how to check if there is "versieGML" tag instead of "versieIMRO"?
Or if the tag names are different in other XML's, how to deal with it?

Comment: How does your `xml` looks like?

Comment: I added xml sample in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to cast `XElement` to string (not `XElement.Value` property which already of type `string`), to avoid NRE in case the element is not found :

```
Version = (string)x.Element("version"),
```

If you want to use `versionX` in case `version` element is not found, try this way :

```
Version = (string)(x.Element("version") ?? x.Element("versionX")),
```

---

Once again, casting `Value` property to `string` on is useless, it doesn't make any difference. If you want to get `string.Empty` instead of `null`, use null-coalescing operator again :

```
Version = (string)(x.Element("version") ?? x.Element("versionX")) ?? string.Empty,
```

Comment: @NitinSoni have you applied this approach on all `x.Element("...").Value`?

Comment: I just edited my code, yes using planInfo.Element("..").Value, without using Value it gives null value

Comment: @NitinSoni Don't do that. Instead, use null-coalescing operator to coalesce to `string.Empty` : `Version = (string)(x.Element("version") ?? x.Element("versionX")) ?? string.Empty`

Comment: I did that, but that returns blank value, i need to have the innerText of either of that tag. please suggest.

Comment: @NitinSoni Look at your XML closely, it is most likely means some `<location>` doesn't have either of that tag that you got blank value.. otherwise, I'd suggest to post minimal sample XML that will demonstrate this problem

Comment: I'll give you link of that xxml, [link](http://ro-online.robeheer.nl/svhw/709B6D57-08F4-4482-AD70-92AC1BF6A243/g_NL.IMRO.1924.NWTWestdijk31en33-BP30.xml)
you may see there is a tag "<versieGML>" sometimes it becomes "<versieIMRO>". I need to read the value of all the tags under "<Eigenschappen>". Please suggest.

Comment: @NitinSoni Look at your XML closely. Can you verify that ***all*** `<Eigenschappen>` has either `<versieGML>` or `<versieIMRO>` child in that XML?

Comment: yes its a specific xml with only one "<Eigenschappen>", which either contains "<versieGML>" or "<versieIMRO>" tags, most of the xml have "<versieIMRO>". I need to read several similar xml's.

Comment: Is that the XML from which you  got empty string? The XML has default namespace (`xmlns="http://www.geonovum.nl/stri/2012/2.0"`). Have your code considered that (f.e using `XNamespace`)?

Comment: yes right, I am using the namespace as well, let me edit in my query. another xml which has "<versieIMRO>" is [link](http://www.hattem.nl/roonline/0269/plannen/NL.IMRO.0269.OV165-/NL.IMRO.0269.OV165-VG01/g_NL.IMRO.0269.OV165-VG01.xml)

Comment: See my previous comment... or can you share your actual test code (if it is short enough)?

Comment: yes, Please check my Question, I edited with adding my C# code, thanks

Comment: @NitinSoni There you go, the use of `ns` is missing initially: `Versie = (string)(planInfo.Element(ns+"VersieIMRO") ?? planInfo.Element(ns + "VersieGML")) ?? string.Empty,`

Comment: ah My Bad, Thanks for the support. I'll mark this as correct answer now.